# Can we use instance in the form?

Tags: django

hello guys i am working on form i didint find how to get instance in the form. This is not a model form

```
def form(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():

else:
    form = Form()

return render(request, 'app/form.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a form class something like below:

### forms.py

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

---

Now To handle the form we need to instantiate it in the view for the URL where we want it to be published:

### views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render

from .forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
        # process the data as required
        # ...
        # redirect to a new URL:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        form = NameForm()

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

Refer the Django documentation for more details.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/